# Scala 2.8.1 implicitly convert to java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

I have a Scala data structure created with the following:

```
List(Map[String, Anyref]("a" -> someFoo, "b" -> someBar))
```

I would like to **implicitly** convert it (using `scala.collection.JavaConversions` or `scala.collection.JavaConverters`) to a `java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Object>>` to be passed the a Java method that expects the latter.

Is this possible?

I have already created the following method that does it, but was wondering if it can be done automatically by the compiler?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
def convertToJava(listOfMaps: List[Map[String, AnyRef]]):
  java.util.List[java.util.Map[String, Object]] = {
  asJavaList(listOfMaps.map(asJavaMap(_)))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about writing

```
implicit def convertToJava...
```

?

Comment: That makes sense, but I was hoping that Scala would do it automatically so I could save 4 lines of code :-).

Comment: This is a quite special case, so I think these 4 lines are okay. Generally over-the-top use of implicit conversion can lead to surprising results, so it's only sensible that the Scala library uses them with caution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want this kind of multilevel conversion happening by magic.  You can improve a little on your own conversion though, at least aesthetically.

```
import java.{ util => ju }
implicit def convert[K, V](xs: List[Map[K, V]]): ju.List[ju.Map[K, V]] = xs map (x => x: ju.Map[K, V])
```

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote just for the import aliasing line - didn't know one could do that!

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at your solution.

Comment: @Esko: I've started using the import aliasing to rename java.* classes: `import java.lang.{Integer => JInteger}` for those rare cases where I have to force autoboxing: `(x: JInteger)`.